# get coordinates on tap in iphone application

Tags: iphone, xcode, mapkit

I am create a iphone Mapkit application. I want to get the coordinates where the user has tapped on the map screen.

Best Regards,
Naveed Rafi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the touch event and then Use convertPoint:toCoordinateFromView:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/convertPoint:toCoordinateFromView: